# Change Akeneo CE 3.2 product default image

Tags: akeneo

Looking to change the default product image file in Akeneo 3.2 CE but for the life of me can't seem to find it other then in the cache. Where would I change the image file or code call out location to change the default image?

Answer (score 0):

Try overwriting the *pim_enrich.provider.default_image* service like described here: https://docs.akeneo.com/3.2/manipulate_pim_data/product_asset/add_asset_default_thumbnail_for_unknown_file_types.html

The doc says: "This cookbook is about a feature only provided in the Enterprise Edition." But should work in CE too. Cause it's just overwriting the service.